# chrome-extension:load data in background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I‘m developing chrome extension.
user log in in options.html,and then application will load much data from web database.
but once user close options.html, the loading process will stop immediately.
I want to do the loading work in background page, but I don't how to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do you loading in [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html).

```
function load_data() { 
    // do something 
}
```

and then call it in your option page.

```
var app = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
app.load_data();
```

then your loading process will keep running in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I will try it immediately!

Comment: It works,thanks again. "any function define in background page can call by any page from extension,and then running in the process of background page", Is it right?

Comment: Only functions of window namespace could be called directly.  And not all extension page have rights to access background directly . Contentscript is an exception, you should use message passing. see: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html